# I want to expand width of div by child divs with fixed height

Tags: css

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div>
                        <div>Hello</div>
                        <div>World of</div>
                        <div>CSS</div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div>
                        <div>Hello</div>
                        <div>World of</div>
                        <div>CSS</div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
    overflow-x:auto;
    width:100px;
    background-color:#D5D5D5;
    height:300px;

}

td > div {
    height:20px; /*fixed height*/
    background-color:white;
}
td > div > div {
    display:inline-block; /*set width by contents*/    
    border:1px solid black;
    float:left;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2s2y5/1/

I want to make divs in td in a row and make x-scroll in container div. 
The size of divs in td must be decided by its contents. Is it possible? 
If I have to replace table to divs, that doesn't matter.
Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1):

The table tag is by default set to fit the page. If u set a width for table then one can expect the x-scroll to work. I have made a certain changes in jsfiddle. Hope this is what u were asking in Cheers.

http://jsfiddle.net/2wvUJ/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is a good solution, but I need to fit table width to its content.